# How to post dateTime to soap webservice from android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

When I post the datestring to server, the time always changes. How can I post the datestring in soap webservices.

```
<Validfrom>dateTime</Validfrom>
```

I convert the string to date object, it posted but the time changes.
plz help me anyone to me

```
private Date getDateObj(String dateInString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(dateInString);
        date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Above code represents my date object and I posted data like:

```
request.addProperty(name.trim(),
                    getDateObj(value));
```

Comment: see my ans dude it will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to calculate server time like GMT because your location is India (according to stack overflow profile). So, you are in +5.30 GMT. That's why you are getting wrong time from server with India time. So, use my code that will give you GMT server time :)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");  
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-06")); 
String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
```

may thz will help u 
**best of luck dude**